# Hibernate update multiple Objects List

Tags: java, hibernate

I have different types of objects to update. All objects are set to a list and pass them to a method.

```
List list =  new ArrayList();
        list.add(mediaInfo); // Class MediaInfo
        list.add(mediaMode); // Class MediaMode
        list.add(paidCustomer); // Class paidCustomer
 updateList ( l );
```

All above objects have loaded before and I have changed one field (called "position" : String value). Also above any object is not attached to any hb session. Those objects are loaded in another place. I just want to update them with updated data.

```
public boolean updateList(java.util.List <Object> dataList){

            Session session = null; 
        Hbutility myHbutil = null;
        try {
            myHbutil = new Hbutility();
            session = myHbutil.getSession();
            Transaction tx = session.beginTransaction();
            for(Object entity: dataList){
            logger.info("Updating Objects :  " + entity );

            session.update( entity ); 
            }
            tx.commit();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();            

        }finally{
            session.close();
        }

         return updateStaus;
     }
```

All objects have their id s. But they are not updated. Any one See any problem here ?
There are many samples of hibernate update in google. But all of them shows, loading a object inside the session, setting new values and simply updating. In my scenario, objects are loaded out of the session and all of them are different type of objects. Any help please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To update the content, you can also use the merge method. Maibe it can help you ?

Try to get objet with the entities manager. Then modify the properties. And save change Exemple :

```
MediaInfo tmp = em.find(MediaInfo.class, mediaInfo.getId();
//Modify some properties
tmp.setMachin(....);
list.add(tmp);
updateList ( list );
```

Comment: Thanks. I want to update the column, but not to save.

Comment: update merge are two method to persist an existing enties. Maibe you can try with session.merge( entity );

Comment: when I tried to merge, There is an exceptin , org.hibernate.TransientObjectException: object references an unsaved transient instance - save the transient instance before flushing: com.media.entity.MediaInfo   .

Comment: how do you get object mediaInfo, mediaMode and paidCustomer. To update entitie you had to get object with the entities manager. After you change some properties and finaly use em.merge(obj). Can you paste or describe the code used to get mediaInfo and other objects ?

Comment: Those are saved into DB through Hibernate and and kept in HttpSession in a previous step. Those savings are successful.

Comment: Can you paste the entities model? if you have id's of the entities, try to reload them before the merge with em.find. exemple MediaInfo tmp = em.find(MediaInfo.class, mediaInfo.getId(); tmp.setTheproperties...(); list.add(tmp));

Comment: Thanks. I tried reloading the entity. EnitiyManager is not used, anyway load the entity with hbSession.get(..).. then merge.. still doesn't work ..  soo bad  for me .. :(

Comment: Can you paste the log ?

Answer (score 0):

Need to ensure that your mapping for 'position' is as per your expectation, ie it should'nt be transient and updatable should'nt be false

Comment: Thanks Jayr for ur  answer. It is not transient and also no any params set updatable false.